# How to use PlayAndRecord session with ability to switch output to Speaker

Tags: ios, avaudiosession, airplay, speaker

I'm writing and iOS audio/video chat app with several pre-conditions:

- I'm using PlayAndRecord category to establish a audio/video chat.
- I have also a button to which allows user to switch to the phone speaker whenever he wants.
- I'm using AirPlay to demo the app.

The issue is once I'm switching to speaker during my PlayAndRecord session I'm losing the AirPlay mirroring. Once speaker is disabled - Airplay is back.

How to handle Speakerphone without losing the AirPlay mirroring?